# How to pass in a parameter into a function?

Tags: android, parameters

I'm trying to add the addcard name parameter in my addCard function under case R.id.btn_billHistory:
How can I pass the name parameter in it? I'm not sure how to solve it. This line is giving me an error.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.btn_billHistory:
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bill History",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BillActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            **addCard();**
            return true;
        case R.id.btn_about:
            openCloseDialog();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void **addCard(String name)** {
    final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_bill, null);

    TextView nameView = view.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    Button delete = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

    nameView.setText(name);

    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            layout.removeView(view);
        }
    });
    layout.addView(view);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `addCard()`functions before start activity

```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.btn_billHistory:
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bill History",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            addCard("Check Bill History");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BillActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            
            return true;
        case R.id.btn_about:
            openCloseDialog();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

    private void **addCard(String name)** {
        final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_bill, null);
    
        TextView nameView = view.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        Button delete = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    
        nameView.setText(name);
    
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                layout.removeView(view);
            }
        });
        layout.addView(view);
    }
```

Comment: what do i replace (your_string_name) with?

Comment: your dersired value that you wanted to pass

Comment: you need to pass the value of in addcard because you have defined the string in addCard function

Comment: should I pass in nameView?

Comment: or pass in R.id.edtName?
I'm really confused

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a string to the `addCard` call in `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Just skimming your code snippet, I would guess it's "Bill History", but the string you pass is up to you.

For example:

```
case R.id.btn_billHistory:
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BillActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    addCard("Bill History");
    return true;
```

However, just noticing your `finish` call, and it doesn't make sense to update any views in current activity if you're just going to start another activity. So you might want to rethink that bit.